# ContainerView not connecting childviews and controller properly

Tags: ember.js

I have an container view defined below

```
app.MainView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
    childViews: ['navigationView', 'gutterView', 'mainView'],
    elementId: 'master',
    navigationView: app.NavView,
    gutterView: app.GutterView,
    mainView: Ember.View.create({
        elementId: 'content',
        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{outlet contentOutlet}}')
    })
});
app.NavView = Ember.View.extend({
    elementId: 'main-menu',
    classNames: ['navigationPanel'],
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{controller}}')
});
app.NavController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    content: [],
});
```

the problem here is that when I define it like this the controller for app.NavView (app.NavController) does not get connected to the view. if I look at the {{controller}} for the NavView through the template i get the ApplicationController.

But when I define it like this:

```
 app.MainView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
    childViews: ['navigationView', 'gutterView', 'mainView'],
    elementId: 'master',
    navigationView: Ember.View.extend({
        elementId: 'nav',
        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{outlet navOutlet}}')
    }),
    gutterView: app.GutterView,
    mainView: Ember.View.create({
        elementId: 'content',
        template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{outlet contentOutlet}}')
    })
});
```

and connect the NavView through the connectOutlet in the router

```
router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('navOutlet', 'nav');
```

I get that the connected controller in NavView is NavController, which is correct!

**The question is, what am I missing here? I don't want an outlet here and want it to be created through the mainView.
Why is Ember not connecting the View and Controller properly when I use an ContainerView?**

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle please ? it seems like this is only a concern of nesting issue, but not sure.

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Energiz0r/SFSnH/2/

Answer (score 1):

The "connection" between view and controller is not as "automagic" as you believed. using the outlets it's done via the call to

```
router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('aOutlet', 'nav');
```

If you walk through the code of https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/system/controller.js#L102 you will see that it's retrieving the controller via naming convention, and then connect the just created view to it.

If you don't want to use outlet here, I suggest you to manually give the controller to the view.

EDIT: To precise why the controller of NavView is Application in the first case:

using the NavView class directly as a child of the mainView, does not bind automatically the NavController to it. So, when you try to get it's controller, it fallbacks to its parentView's controller,.

Comment: I think I formulated the question a bit wrong. The outlet part of the fiddle is not the problem, that is working as excpected. I just included that to show that it has connected the NavController correct. The problem here is that when i create the NavView inside the ContainerView(as one of the childViews), and not through an outlet, the NavView gets connected to the ApplicationController, and not the NavController as I excpected

Comment: Not really, is it by design that Controllers don't get connected to their respective Views when using a ContainerView? What is the point of a ContainerView then? To only have views without Controllers?

Comment: I'm probably missing a huge point here, but right now I don't see the use of a ContainerView :)

Comment: I saw you issue on github, I think you could link this question.
That said, currently, when the ContainerView instantiate its child views, it does not inject a controller (like connectOutlet do). Perhaps it could be a feature to add.

Comment: Yea. Maybe my understanding of a ContainerView is wrong. My solution is to add multiple outlets to my topview, and connect my 'childViews' to these outlets. Will work on this and see if I get any response on my git issue before entering an answer. Tnx for you help sly!

Comment: What I see here could be a typical use case of outlets. The idea is to connect each part with one outlet. I think this is a pretty neat approach to desing the app.